# MySQL query to Delete part of the value in a cell

Tags: mysql

I want to delete part of the value withing a cell.  The part I want to delete begins and ends with `</br>`.

Cell Value Example:

```
This house is red.</br><img src="someimage.png" style="margin-bottom: 3px;"/></a></br>
```

I want to delete `</br><img src="someimage.png" style="margin-bottom: 3px;"/></a></br>`

How would I write this query?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name SET fiele = REPLACE(field, 'old string', 'new_string');
```

But is better remove extra string server side, before insert in db.